# XSLT < instead of &lt; throws an exception

Tags: xml, xslt, operators

I have a line where I'm calculating seconds to minutes. The following line below works perfectly fine.

```
<xsl:if test="$value &gt; 60 and $value &lt; 3600 or $value - 3600 >= 1">
```

Notifce the `>=` is being used without an exception. But if I use this following line below, it will throw an exception:

```
<xsl:if test="$value > 60 and $value < 3600 or $value - 3600 >= 1">
```

results in:

```
xsltproc index.xsl all.xml > index.html
index.xsl:238: parser error : Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
    <xsl:if test="$value<60 or $value = 60 or $value - 60 >= 1">
```

It doesn't seem to like `$value < 3600` or `$value < '3600'` but is willing to accept `$value > 3600` and `$value > '3600'`

Why?!

Comment: try ($value > 60 and $value < 3600 or $value - 3600) >= 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### XML Standard

This is what the [XML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#syntax) has to say about it:

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings "&" and "<" respectively. The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the string ">", and MUST, for compatibility, be escaped using either ">" or a character reference when it appears in the string "]]>" in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section.

#### Why must we escape `<` ?

If the standard did not force you to escape `<` when you want this character to be character data rather than marking the start of a tag, parsing a valid document in some cases would be impossible. Let's say that you want to have a single paragraph, which in the system you use is represented with the element `p` (like in XHTML, or in the TEI standard) and in this paragraph you wish to place this text:

> Execute the command "foo <div>" where "<div>" is the division that you want to foo.

If you could represent `<` as `<`, it would look like this:

```
<p>Execute the command "foo <div>" where "<div>" is the division that you want to foo.</p>
```

There's no way for the parser to know that `<div>` is meant to be interpreted as character data, and not as an opening tag. You could have just as valid a case where `<div>` is meant to be an opening tag for an XML element (which it is, both in XHTML and TEI).

#### Why are we not required to escape `>`?

The reason we do not need to escape `>` (the standard says we "may" escape it) is that the rule that requires that we escape `<` by the same token makes the interpretation of `>` completely determined by context. In other words, the parser can interpret it unambiguously.

And this is why the parser is completely fine if you put `>=` or `>` in your attribute but not `<`.

Answer (score 2):

The [XML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/) disallows unescaped '<' in most locations, including attribute values.

This is because '<' is the start character of the basic XML tag structure, and disallowing it elsewhere makes parsing possible.

XSLT has to be valid XML, so the same rules apply there.

Comment: Then there's no way to go around it other than `&lt;`?

Comment: @tyler Best get used to it - unless you prefer to write all your comparisons in the > direction, e.g. `3600 > $value and $value > 60`. BTW, converting seconds to minutes (and, presumably, to hours) can be done without all these comparisons, just by integer division and mod.